# Invalid Login attempts in Lightswitch 2012 and requiresQuestionAndAnswer

Tags: asp.net-membership, visual-studio-lightswitch

In my Lightswitch 2012 app if I provide the incorrect password 5 times it locks me out with "Maximum sign in attempts have been exceeded".

I have this default membership configuration in my web.config:

```
<add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="_IntrinsicData" applicationName="BMS" requiresUniqueEmail="false" **requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"** />
```

[According to MSDN this should not happen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx):  "If the *RequiresQuestionAndAnswer property is set to false,* invalid password-answer attempts are not tracked."

I have this set to False...  the only way I can turn off InvalidPasswordAttempt tracking is to add a ridiculously high **maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="100000"** (which works but seems hacky). Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've not had that experience myself (but I've never tried getting the password wrong 5 times), so I can't say if that's the correct way to handle it, but it's unlikely. As you say, it seems quite a "hack" to have to do that.

If LS is ignoring the *RequiresQuestionAndAnswer* property then I'd consider that a bug. However there *may* be a reason for it. You could log a bug on the [LS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/site1231/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=4960&FeedbackType=1) website, & see what the response is there. Or you could ask the question in the [Visual Studio LightSwitch - General Questions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/threads/) forum (I don't know if the team monitors questions here, but I know they're active in the LS forum).

Comment: Hi Yann, I noticed another "bug" - everytime I change the web config and do a new deploy it overwrites it! So for example I changed the length of the password requirements and it keeps overwriting it...

Comment: Where are you making the change? In the Server project's web.config file? In the web.config that's in a subfolder of your publish folder? Or in the actual deployed web.config file?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was being a plonker - I changed it in the project and it all works now